Use basic Drag&Drop With A tree in PrimeNG
I work with primeng (v.17.18).
I want to use their drag&drop system. I have no problem using it, or even Tree.
However, I'd like to use a mix of the two.
I have a list of items on one side that I want to drop into a tree.
Something like :
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Source -->
    <div class="list-container">
      <h3>Source</h3>
      <ul>
        <li
          *ngFor="let item of sourceList"
          pDraggable="treeItems"
          [dragData]="item"
          [ngStyle]="{ cursor: 'move' }"
        >
          {{ item }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  
    <!-- P-Tree -->
    <div class="tree-container">
      <h3>Tree</h3>
      <p-tree
        [value]="treeNodes"
        [draggableNodes]="false"
        droppableNodes="true"
        pDroppable="treeItems"
        (onNodeDrop)="onNodeDrop($event)"
      ></p-tree>
    </div>
  </div>

But cane doesn't work. And I don't even know if I can make it work...
One solution would be to override the CSS style of the  and have a “flat” tree for Drag and Drop into a basic tree.
Thanks for your advice
